# Targetting animation/keyframes inside seperate divs

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-animations

I am trying to hover to pause functionality to my pure css slider. At one point I had it pausing, but then I wanted to add in a div displaying that it is paused. It came to my attention during this process, that one element can not action another element coming before it. So I put the "pause display div", and the pictures, into a "slider_cover" div in order to action elements coming after itself. I am able to action the "pause display div," but now the pictures in the div immediately after the "pause display div." I just need to know how/which selectors to use to action both divs, one into showing itself, and the other into "animation-play-state: paused;"

The following is the code I am working with:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slider_cover"></div>
    <div id="pause" class="pause">
        <p>Paused</p>
    </div>
    <div id="slider_bg">
            <div class="picslider">         
                <img id="pic1" class="slide pause" src="./Pictures/pic1.png"></img>
                <img id="pic2" class="slide pause" src="./Pictures/pic2.png"></img>
                <img id="pic3" class="slide pause" src="./Pictures/pic3.png"></img>
            <div id="progress" class="pause"> </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#pause p {
position: relative;
font-size: 32pt;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: 25px;
text-align: center;
color: white;

}
#slider_cover {
position: absolute;
top: 135px;
left: 250px;
opacity: 0;
width: 750px;
height: 550px;
z-index: 12;
}
#slider_cover:hover + #pause{
max-height: 100px;
}
#slider_cover:hover img:nth-of-type(1) {
animation-play-state: paused;
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
-moz-animation-play-state: paused;
-o-animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Sorry ahead of time for the mass of CSS. Please stick to CSS/HTML answers, And thanks for any effort in advance!!

Comment: Could you move the solution into an answer below instead? That way your question can then be marked as answered. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I will now. It would not allow me to post my solution as an answer so soon after asking the question. It wanted me to wait 8 hours, and I didn't intend to return to this question. Glad someone saw this at least!

Comment: @Cody you can mark your answer as accepted by clicking the check-mark next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**!!!SOLVED!!!**

I figured it out. I moved the "slider_cover's" closing tag, so that it would encompass both divs I wished to action on. I tried this before, but was deterred by previously set "position" tags. Once I altered the positions accordingly I used the "element element" selector to action my div "pause" , and class ".pause"(pertaining to, two separate divs)

The following are the important bits of my solution code to compare to my previous code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slider_cover">
<div id="pause" class="pause">
    <p>Paused</p>
</div>
<div id="slider_bg">
        <div class="picslider">         
            <img id="pic1" class="slide pause" src="./Pictures/pic1.png"></img>
            <img id="pic2" class="slide pause" src="./Pictures/pic2.png"></img>
            <img id="pic3" class="slide pause" src="./Pictures/pic3.png"></img>
        <div id="progress" class="pause"> </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#slider_cover {
position: absolute;
top: 140px;
left: 250px;
background: orange;
width: 750px;
height: 550px;
z-index: 10;
}
#slider_cover:hover > #pause{
max-height: 100px;
}
#slider_cover:hover  .pause{
animation-play-state: paused;
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
-moz-animation-play-state: paused;
-o-animation-play-state: paused;
}
```